# Adding two arrays to two columns in JavaFX TableView

Tags: java, javafx

I have successfully added one array to one column in `TableView` with the following code:

```
data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

    String[] a = {"a", "b"};

    yearColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<test3, String>("Year"));
    interestColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<test3, String>("Interest"));
    principalColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<test3, String>("Principal"));
    balanceColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<test3, String>("Balance"));

    paymentsAnnual.setItems(data);

    for (String anA : a) {
        test3 test31 = new test3();
        test31.year.setValue(anA);
        data.add(test31);
    }
```

test3.java

```
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;

public class test3 {

    public SimpleStringProperty year = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty interest = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty principal = new SimpleStringProperty();
    public SimpleStringProperty balance = new SimpleStringProperty();

    public String getYear() {
        return year.get();
    }


    public String getInterest() {
        return interest.get();
    }


    public String getPrincipal() {
        return principal.get();
    }


    public String getBalance() {
        return balance.get();
    }

}
```

Now I have a problem when I try to insert a new array to a different column at a time. say I have an array `String[] b = {"hello", "hi"}`, then I add it using the same for each loop, something like this

```
for (String anA : a) {
            test3 test31 = new test3();
            test31.year.setValue(anA);
            data.add(test31);
        }
for (String anA1 : b) {
            test3 test31 = new test3();
            test31.balance.setValue(anA1);
            data.add(test31);
        }
```

this adds the array but I get an output something like this

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to add them together?

**UPDATE**

How should I add array `a` and `b` together, which would give an output like this
[image]

**UPDATE-2**

I do have one way of doing it , by making it a double array

```
String[] a = {{"a", "b"},{"hello","hi"}};
for (int i = 1; i < a[0].length; i++){
     test3 test31 = new test3();
     test31.year.setValue(a[0][i]);
     test31.balance.setValue(a[1][i]);
     data.add(test31);
}
```

this way I am able to add the contents at a time in its correct row, what if its a single array?

Comment: What exactly is the question? Do you want the "hello, hi" in the same row than "a, b"? If so, you need to get the already created objects from your data first and then add the "hello, hi" to your objects.

Answer (score 2):

Every item in a TableView's items list represents one row.

Your first loop adds two rows, which each have a `year` defined but have no other properties defined.

Your second loop adds two more rows, which each have a `balance` defined but have no other properties defined.

You must modify the existing objects in your List instead of adding more rows.